# How to replace a string from a default position?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$text = "abc def abc jkl mno";
    $regex = '/'.trim('abc').'/ism';
    $search = array();
    if(preg_match_all($regex, $text, $tmp)) {
       if(isset($tmp[0])) {             
          for($i = 0;$i < count($tmp[0]); $i++) {
            $search = $tmp[0][1];
            $replace = 'ghi';
            $article = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);   
          }
       }
    }
        echo $article;
```

When I `echo $article_text` the result is: `ghi def ghi jkl mno`

But the result I want is `abc def ghi jkl mno`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You'd probably want the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE option for preg_match_all, so you get both the matched strings AND their string offsets: http://php.net/preg_match_all

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dJZIJk

```
$text = "abc def abc jkl mno";
$search = 'abc';
$replace = 'ghi';
$article = substr($text, 0, strlen($search)) . str_replace($search, $replace, substr($text, strpos($text, 'abc') + strlen($search)));
echo $article;
```